# A 'top 100' app that displays list of users ordered in two different ways

Tags: ecmascript-6, react.js, sass, jsx

I built a small app that gets data from a remote json file and displays it in a list of users. In each list item, an image of the user, their name, and their points tallies are shown.

The list is displayed in two possible ways - 'all time' and 'recent' - depending on the user's choice.

I would specifically like feedback for my SCSS and usage of React components but anything else is also welcome.

PS: I tried working without semicolons - is this a good or bad idea?

[Here is a Codepen](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/full/Ywpoog)

Javascript:

```
const Header = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="header col-xs-12">
            <div className="col-xs-8">
                <h6><a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/">FreeCodeCamp</a></h6>
                <h1>Top100</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-4">
                <select className="form-control" id="time-toggle" onChange={props.handleSelect} value={props.value}>
                    <option value="recent">Past 30 days</option>
                    <option value="alltime">All time</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Panels = (props) => {
    const {listOfCampers} = props
    const lines = listOfCampers.map((e, i) => {
        return (
            <li className="panel" key={i}>
                <a href={`http://www.freecodecamp.com/${e.username}`} target="_blank">
                <div className="panel-inner">
                    <img className="img-responsive" src={e.img}/>

                    <div className="number">
                        <h5>{i + 1}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div className="info">
                        <h5>{e.username}</h5>
                        {props.value === 'recent'
                        // Adjust output depending on select
                        ?
                        <div>
                            <p>Past 30 Days: {e.recent}</p>
                            <p>All time: {e.alltime}</p>
                        </div>
                        :
                        <div>
                            <p>All time: {e.alltime}</p>
                            <p>Past 30 Days: {e.recent}</p>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                {lines}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

const Loading = () => <div className="loading"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <div className="footer">Made by <a href="http://www.github.com/alanbuchanan">alanbuchanan</a></div>
    )
}

const Main = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            data: [],
            value: 'recent'
        }
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getCampers()
    },

    // Only pass 'recent' or 'alltime' in
    getCampers() {
        const url = `http://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/${this.state.value}`
        $.getJSON(url, dataFromSource => {

            if(this.state.value === 'recent'){
                dataFromSource.sort((a, b) => { return a.recent > b.recent ? -1 : a.recent < b.recent ? 1 : 0 })
            } else { // alltime
                dataFromSource.sort((a, b) => { return a.alltime > b.alltime ? -1 : a.alltime < b.alltime ? 1 : 0 })
            }
            this.setState({data: dataFromSource})
        })
    },

    changeFromSelect(event) {
        // UX: Re-initilising state.data triggers `Loading`. Without it, no loading message.
        this.setState({data: []})
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        }, () => {
            this.getCampers()
        })
    },

    render(){
        const {data} = this.state
        const {value} = this.state
        const loading = data.length === 0
        return (
            <div>
                <Header handleSelect={this.changeFromSelect} value={value}/>
                {loading ? <Loading /> :
                <div>
                    <Panels listOfCampers={data} value={value} />
                    <Footer />
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100);
$primary-color: #FCF5B8;
$bg-color: #B4CD93;
$info-bg-color: dimgray;
$number-bg-color: #FCF5B8;
$number-text-color: dimgray;
$infobox-height: 70px;
$box-width: 97%;
$font-stack: 'Roboto Slab', serif;

body {
  background: $bg-color;
  font-family: $font-stack;
  font-weight: 100;
}

select {
  //-webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: whitesmoke !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  //height: 100px;
  div {
    padding: 0;
    h6 {
      font-weight: 400;
      letter-spacing: 1.5px;
      a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
    h1 {
      font-weight: 400;

    }
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

img {
  width: $box-width;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  color: $primary-color;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.loading {
  text-align: center;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .info {
    padding: 5px 5px 75px 15px;
  }

  :hover {
    img {
      -webkit-filter: brightness(0.9);
    }
    .info {
      background-color: $number-bg-color;
      h5, p {
        color: black;
      }
    }

  }
}


.panel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.number {
  background-color: $number-bg-color;
  h5 {
    color: $number-text-color !important;
  }
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.info {
  background-color: $info-bg-color;
  width: $box-width;
  height: $infobox-height;
  div {
    p:nth-of-type(2) {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
}

p {
  color: white
}

select {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.footer {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

// GRID........................

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {

  .panel {
    width: 50%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

  .panel:nth-of-type(1),
  .panel:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 50%
  }
  .panel {
    width: 33.333%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  .panel:nth-of-type(1),
  .panel:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 50%
  }
  .panel:nth-of-type(3),
  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
    width: 33.333%
  }
  .panel {
    width: 25%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .panel:nth-of-type(1),
  .panel:nth-of-type(2),
  .panel:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 33.333%
  }
  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5),
  .panel:nth-of-type(6),
  .panel:nth-of-type(7) {
    width: 25%
  }

  .panel {
    width: 20%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1301px) {
  .panel:nth-of-type(1),
  .panel:nth-of-type(2),
  .panel:nth-of-type(3),
  .panel:nth-of-type(4) {
    width: 25%
  }

  .panel:nth-of-type(5),
  .panel:nth-of-type(6),
  .panel:nth-of-type(7),
  .panel:nth-of-type(8),
  .panel:nth-of-type(9) {
    width: 20%
  }

  .panel {
    width: 14.285%
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this by chance your entry for [this](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/zipline-build-a-camper-leaderboard) challenge?

Comment: @Mast It sure is!

Comment: That challenge requires a table format as output. Whether your output is a table is ambiguous. You may want to update your question with the information that usage of SASS and React.js is a condition of the challenge, not optional. This should hopefully eliminate answers recommending a different framework altogether. Best of luck!

Comment: I'd like to review this code, but it appears as though it doesn't comply with the challenge. Also, it would be best if you state that it's part of some other site's challenge and include its guidelines, screenshot etc. Let's make the post meaningful, so that when the challenge page goes down, the post will still have meaning.